# If column value in separate dataframes match, add separate columns together (if column value is greater than zero)

Tags: pandas, sorting, match, addition

I have two dataframes, we will call them a and b. I would like to sort through them and pull out the values in the 'color' columns that appear in both dataframes, then add the column 'scalar_y' in dataframe a to dataframe b, and add column 'scalar z' in dataframe a to dataframe b, but only if the existing value in dataframe b is greater than zero.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'color':['purple','yellow','red','green','blue', 'violet','black'], 'scalar_y':[1,2,0,5,7,9,10], 'scalar_z':[2,4,6,8,10,12,10]}
a = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

[dataframe a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxTTW.png)

```
dict2 = {'color':['purple','yellow','yellow','green','blue', 'violet','violet'], 'x':['ducks','geese','moose','bear','acorn','seagull','worm'],'y':[10,20,0,50,70,90,100], 'z':[20,40,60,80,100,120,0]}
b = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

[dataframe b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6dyP.png)

The desired output would look like this:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol3dk.png)

What I have so far is a forloop that picks out the shared colors, but I can't get the addition to work:

```
empty = pd.DataFrame()
for color in a.color:
    new_df = b.loc[b['color'].str.contains(color)]
    new_df['y'] = new_df['y'].apply(lambda x: '0' if x==0 else new_df['y'] = new_df['y'].add(a['scalar_y'], axis=0))
    empty = pd.concat([empty,new_df])
    #print(new_df)
empty
```

I would set up the same lambda function for new_df['z'] if this had worked. Ultimately I would like to update b with the resulting 'empty' dataframe, maybe there is a more direct way to do this. My coding skills are novice, apologies for the poor attempt here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with left join and add columns in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) if greate like `0` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), for remove columns use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
c = (b.merge(a, on='color', how='left')
       .assign(y = lambda x: x.y.mask(x.y.gt(0), x.y.add(x.pop('scalar_y'))),
               z = lambda x: x.z.mask(x.z.gt(0), x.z.add(x.pop('scalar_z')))))

print (c)
    color        x    y    z
0  pruple    ducks   11   22
1  yellow    geese   22   44
2  yellow    moose    0   64
3   green     bear   55   88
4    blue    acorn   77  110
5  violet  seagull   99  132
6  violet     worm  109    0
```

Another idea with mapping:

```
c = (b.assign(y=lambda x:x.y.mask(x.y.gt(0), 
                                  x.y.add(x.color.map(a.set_index('color')['scalar_y']))),
              z=lambda x:x.z.mask(x.z.gt(0), 
                                  x.z.add(x.color.map(a.set_index('color')['scalar_z'])))))

print (c)
    color        x    y    z
0  pruple    ducks   11   22
1  yellow    geese   22   44
2  yellow    moose    0   64
3   green     bear   55   88
4    blue    acorn   77  110
5  violet  seagull   99  132
6  violet     worm  109    0
```